# Underlining 3 words at a time in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

In WPF, how would I do the following:

1. Every x milliseconds, underline 3 words at a time. After x milliseconds, underline the next 3 words.
2. Every x milliseconds, have 3 words appear and disappear from the window?

If I were to use Windows Forms, is there still a way of doing (1) and (2) above?

Thank you

Comment: I think we need a little more information. First, what control is housing the text that needs to be underlined? Do you want #1 and #2 to happen simultaneously? Can you give us an example of why you want to do this, to better understand what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No, I don't want 1 and 2 to happen simultaneously.
The text that needs this animation is either in a textbox control or an array of strings. 
I need to do this for a project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

You will create a thread which will do (1) and (2). Take into account that actual interaction with UI should be done by means of `Dispatcher` i.e. `window.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`.

To host words you can use ItemsControl with custom ItemsPanelTemplate = WrapPanel.

To host text I suggest you to use TextBlock.

Underlining is done by means of TextBlock.TextDecorations property.

Comment: How would I do (1). I am not sure which part of your answer addresses that. Thanks

Comment: If you will give here some details on the difficulties you bumped into or if you will elaborate your original problem, then you will have much clear responses. My response was as abstract as was your question.